# Extract email addresses from excel sheet and send through outlook

Tags: c#

I am trying to extract email is from excel sheet which is on the 3rd column and 
when I try to run it, it only take first email id and send the message through outlook, then take the second email address and print it but not send the message. can anybody help me? 
Thanks in Advance..

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Create COM Objects. Create a COM object for everything that is referenced
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\bhavna.parmar\Documents\Addressbook.xlsx");
            Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
            Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

            int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
            int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

            // Create the Outlook application.
            //Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
            // Create a new mail item.
            Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            Outlook.Recipients oRecips = oMsg.Recipients;

            try {

                //iterate over the rows and columns and print to the console as it appears in the file
                //excel is not zero based!!
                for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
                    {
                        //new line
                        if (j == 1)
                            Console.Write("\r\n");

                        //write the value to the console
                        if (xlRange.Cells[i, j] != null && xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null)
                            //Console.Write(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString() + "\t");

                            if (j == 3)
                            {
                                for (j = 3, i = i + 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
                                {
                                    Console.Write(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString() + "\t");
                                    //abc = xlRange.Cells[i,j].get
                                    List<string> maillist = new List<string>(); 
                                    maillist.Add(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString());
                                    MailMessage obj_MailMsg = new MailMessage();
                                    foreach (string to in maillist)

                                                //foreach(string to in xlRange.Cells[i,j].Value2.ToString())
                                    {
                                         obj_MailMsg.To.Add(to);
                                        //maillist.Add(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString());
                                        Outlook.Recipient oTORecip = oRecips.Add(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString());
                                        oTORecip.Type = (int)Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olTo;
                                        oTORecip.Resolve();

                                    }                                   

                                    // Set HTMLBody. 
                                    //add the body of the email
                                    oMsg.HTMLBody = "Hello, your message body will go here!!";
                                    //Add an attachment.
                                    String sDisplayName = "MyAttachment";
                                    int iPosition = (int)oMsg.Body.Length + 1;
                                    int iAttachType = (int)Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue;
                                    //now attached the file
                                    Outlook.Attachment oAttach = oMsg.Attachments.Add(@"C:\Users\bhavna.parmar\Documents\Book1.xlsx", iAttachType, iPosition, sDisplayName);
                                    //Subject line
                                    oMsg.Subject = "Your Subject will go here.";
                                    oMsg.Send();
                                    Console.WriteLine("Message sent");

                                    // Clean up.
                                    oRecips = null;
                                    oRecips = null;

                                    oMsg = null;
                                    oApp = null;


                                }
                            }



                    }
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {

                //status(ex.Message, Color.Red);

            }//end of catch

            //cleanup
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            //rule of thumb for releasing com objects:
            //  never use two dots, all COM objects must be referenced and released individually
            //  ex: [somthing].[something].[something] is bad

            //release com objects to fully kill excel process from running in the background
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlRange);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet);

            //close and release
            xlWorkbook.Close();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);

            //quit and release
            xlApp.Quit();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
            //Console.Write("sdjakkas");


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you trace it

Comment: during debug, I can see there is count= 0 and after 1. so 2nd record print but message can not sent

Comment: its really hard to work out what your code needs to do with out an example of some data..

Comment: for example ;  third column is email and their data is abc@company.com at 2nd row, def@company.com at 3rd row and xyz@company.com at 4th row.

Comment: at first row, name of the column, like No, Name and Email

Comment: that makes no sense.. can you please put in some example data like that but in the format in your spreadsheet.. as your code is also doing weird stuff for (j = 3, i = i + 1; i <= rowCount; i++) .. this line so much seems wrong...

Comment: just show a picture.. it isnt making sense

Comment: I put j==3 because I want to take data only from third column and from 2nd row so that's why I put I=I+1 that means I =0 so it start taking value from 2nd row

Comment: if you can show a picture, because you have 2 loops looping round rows and columns then you seem to ignore and try and do it all again inside the two loops

Comment: Right now I cannot help you because I havent got data to look at.. if you cannot or will not show me an example of your data layout..

Comment: I already show you dear. this is the data

Comment: No you wrote words which clearly mean more to you than me - I want a picture of your excel spreadsheet...

Comment: how I send it to you. help me

Comment: Load it up on imgur, and put a link in here

Comment: I tried, but I can't.

Comment: can not load on imgur

Comment: why not? how can you not load on imgur? whatever you go with, there are many sites I cannot get to from work - and i need to see a picture because your description doesnt mean enough.. your code seems to loop every cell and then ignore the fact it was doing so.. there is probably a lot wrong.. but I cant be sure until I see it